# How to load and resample (MP3) audio files faster in Python/Linux?

Tags: python, audio, mp3, audio-processing, librosa

Currently, I am trying to load 280,000 MP3 audio files in Python where the average duration of files is ~5 seconds. I am using [Librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/) for this purpose as well as for the further processing (e.g. computing spectrogram) in later stages.

However, I realized that loading the files is very slow, as on average it takes 370 milliseconds for each file to be loaded, uncompressed and re-sampled. If I turn off the re-sampling (i.e. `librosa.load(..., sr=None)`), it takes around 200 milliseconds but that's not still good considering the large number of files I have. Unsurprisingly, loading wav files without re-sampling is very fast (< 1 ms); but if we perform the re-sampling, it takes around 160 milliseconds.

Now I was wondering if there is any faster approach for doing this, whether directly in Python or using external tools in Linux with the condition that I can later load the results back to Python.

By the way, I have tried using `multiprocessing` with a pool of size 4 and achieved 2-3x speed-up, but I am looking for more (preferably > 10x).

**Note:** the original files are human voice and have a sample rate of 48KHz and a bit-rate of 64 Kbps; I want to downsample them to 16KHz.

Comment: You could try [pysox](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox).

Comment: @hendrik Thanks a lot! I tried `pysox` by downsampling and converting mp3 files to wav and on average it took 20 milliseconds for each file. Much better, even better than `ffmpeg` which I also tried and it took 100 milliseconds for the same operation.

Comment: Cool. I'll make it a real answer.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but I can't see how to simply read the mp3 file without doing any conversion?

Comment: If by "conversion" you are only referring to resampling step, then it's possible to not perform resampling; however, for MP3 files (unlike wav files), I guess they should be at least uncompressed/decoded first to get the raw samples, so that step would be required at least (though, I am not an expert on that topic).

Answer (score 7):

You could use [pysox](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox).

It's a thin Python wrapper around [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net), "the Swiss Army knife of sound processing programs."

**Note:** For faster processing (avoiding exec calls), you may also install and use [soxbindings](https://github.com/pseeth/soxbindings). All you need to do is to replace

```py
import sox
```

with

```py
import soxbindings as sox
```